# the problem with leaflet and leaflet draw vue leaflet.draw.js?20d6:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, leaflet-draw

```
mounted() {
 this.initMap();
},
methods: {
initMap() {
  this.map = L.map('mapContainer').setView([48.856663, 2.351556], 12);
  this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
      "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}",
      {
        attribution: '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery (c) <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: "mapbox/satellite-streets-v11",
        accessToken: "token",
      }
  );
  this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);
  var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
  this.map.addLayer(drawnItems);
  var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
      featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
  });
  this.map.addControl(drawControl);

  this.map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(event){
    let layer = event.layer;
    console.log(`start ${layer}`);
    drawnItems.addLayer((layer))
  })
 },
},
}
```

leaflet.draw.js?20d6:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

After the first interaction with the map, errors appear in the console and it is no longer possible to draw shapes

UPD:Switched to [mapbox draw](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem like this.
Instead of Leaflet, **use MapBox and MapBox draw works in Vue 3**

Comment: Leaflet is free and opensource, mapbox not :(

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar code to draw a polygon on a basemap and have a similar issue when using Vue3 with leaflet and leaflet-draw. After drawing a polygon, I get a bunch of errors in the console, probably triggered by a mouseover event.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._markers is undefined
in leaflet-draw.js:162:18
```

Haven't found the root cause of the problem yet but the reason might be the fact that leaflet-draw is not in line with the Leaflet Base Library any more (just a guess). The last commit at [Github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) is from 2018 and there is a long list of [issues](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues) and open [pull requests](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/pulls), while Leaflet itself is continously updated.

The problem might also occur when using the library in combination with Vue.

Have you tried creating the above functionality using Vanilla JS?

Comment: Thanks for the answer

No, I haven't tried to do it on Vanilla JS, I need to implement drawing objects on the map on VUE 3, in fact this problem is not critical, since the functionality itself works (drawing polygons, polygons, etc.)

But now I have another difficulty, I don't understand how to store the data that I received from the user so that the delete button would work, I understand that each new polyline or polygon is a new layer, but how do I then convert it to GeoJSON, I didn't find in the documentation how to get the current objects on the map

Comment: I have been using leaflet and I have also faced this issue when using vue3 but works well with vue2. If you found the solution kindly give some pointers

Comment: @DKasane I have the problem in VueJS3 but with the same code I haven't the error. The error is bound to VueJS.